# How can I set group permissions that filter pages according to their owners in Wagtail

Tags: django, permissions, wagtail

I am working on a blog with Wagtail and would like to give users access to create their own content in the Wagtail admin. I would like users to be able to log into the Wagtail admin, but only have access to content that they have created themselves.

I have tried to generate permissions by group, however there is no default option to limit content by author, so if I give add, edit and publish permissions, a user could edit content created by other users and could unpublish or even delete that content.

I would like to know if there is a way to modify the queryset of pages that appear in the Wagtail admin for a specific user.

I don't have much experience with Wagtail. So far I have seen some possible solutions but none have seemed viable or adequate.

For example, there are some posts here where they propose to create a Parent page for each user, but then you would have to create a group for each user, which doesn't seem like an efficient way to do it.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Here I share some of the relevant code:

```
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    max_count = 1
    subpage_types = [
        "blog.PostPage",
    ]

    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("intro")
    ]

    def get_template(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.htmx:
            return "blog/components/blog_post_items.html"
        return "blog/blog_index_page.html"


    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        context = super().get_context(request)
        blog_posts = self.get_children().live().filter(alias_of_id__isnull=True).order_by('-first_published_at')
        paginator = Paginator(blog_posts, 3) #@todo: update paginator
        page = request.GET.get("page")
        try:
             blog_posts = paginator.page(page)

        except PageNotAnInteger:
             blog_posts = paginator.page(1)

        except EmptyPage:
             print("No results for page:", page)
             blog_posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
             
        context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts
        
        return context



class PostPage(Page):
    subpage_types = []
    subtitle = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    intro = models.TextField(help_text="Text to describe the page", blank=True)
    featured_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
        help_text="Landscape mode only; horizontal width between 1000px and 3000px.",
    )
    body = StreamField(
        BaseStreamBlock(), verbose_name="Page body", blank=True, use_json_field=True
    )
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=PostPageTag, blank=True)
    date_published = models.DateField(
         "Date article published", 
         blank=True, 
         null=True,
         default=datetime.datetime.today
         )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField("title"),
        index.SearchField("subtitle"),
        index.SearchField("intro"),
        index.SearchField("body"),
    ]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.get_url()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
         FieldPanel("subtitle"),
         FieldPanel("intro"),
         FieldPanel("featured_image"),
         FieldPanel("body"),
         FieldPanel("tags"),
        #  InlinePanel('customcomments', label="Comments"),
    ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If the author is not set, set it to the currently logged-in user
        if not self.author_id and self.owner:
            self.author = self.owner
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```